# A better understanding of SECURED Cookies

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I work on a web application (asp-mvc). 
We have a requirement to always use cookies that are **secured**.
I've read that I should add in my application's web config:
[image]

and this secures my cookies when I publish my application.

Now, the issue is that in our development environment we use HTTP protocol and only in our production environment we use HTTPS protocol.

In the first page of the my application, I have a captcha authentication (we use dll of [captchaMVC](https://captchamvc.codeplex.com/)).
After I secure my cookies by adding the mentioned code in web.config (in our development environment), the captcha page does not load propertly. 
I have a thought that maybe it is because I try to use secured cookies over HTTP (instead of HTTPS) in my development environment, and maybe in production environment everything is going to work properly.
Сould anyone shed more light on the topic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
HttpCookie.Secure = true;
```

The [documentation for HttpCookie.Secure property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcookie.secure(v=vs.110).aspx) states:

*Gets or sets a value indicating whether to transmit the cookie using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL)--that is, over HTTPS only.*

This is confusing.

The underlying truth is, the cookie will always be sent to the client regardless of whether the connection is secure or not.

This is necessary because of two main reasons. First, your application servers may reside behind a firewall/NLB which has the SSL certificate for your web site for achieving [SSL offloading](http://www.ehow.com/facts_7519825_ssl-offloading.html), and second, you may display your web site over a non-secure connection (a web site with a login partial view) and post the login form back through a secure connection and may want one of your cookies to be passed back only if the connection is secure.

The point is, this is only effective on the client side. The browsers will decide whether to send the cookie back or not, depending on the communications protocol selected for the current request.

Here is what I have using secure cookies over a non-secure connection.

```
Response Haders:

Response    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control   private
Content-Type    text/html; charset=utf-8
Server  Microsoft-IIS/8.0
Set-Cookie  ASP.NET_SessionId=xxwcvdn22lietdqtvirucxzv; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
X-AspNet-Version    4.0.30319
Set-Cookie  My=My Cookie Value; path=/; secure
X-Powered-By    ASP.NET
Date    Fri, 27 Nov 2015 13:14:00 GMT
Content-Length  510
```

And for the post back:

```
Request Headers:

Request GET /Default2.aspx HTTP/1.1
Accept  text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*
Accept-Language tr-TR
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Host    localhost:59442
DNT 1
Connection  Keep-Alive
```

Therefore, You should not specify `HttpCookie.Secure = true;` for the development environment, or any environment (test, preprod, branches etc.) that does not support SSL. This means having different web.config files for those environments, which is anyways a requirement if you keep connection string etc. in your web.config file.

The answer of your question would be, yes, it should work on an environment where the web site is accessed through a secure connection (https)

You can check whether the cookie is sent back or not with the developer tools of your favorite browser for any environment.

Comment: @guz Ozgul, thank you for your detailed answer (+1).
I will probably mark this as the accepted answer, I just want to wait till Tuesday when the version is uploaded to production and check that it all works as expected.

Comment: You are welcome. Please make sure to test your application with SSL before deploying to production. Getting a temporary SSL certificate is easy and is free